# Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to update google using terminal, but everytime i try to use `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`, i get this message:

```
E: Não foi possível obter trava /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Recurso temporariamente indisponível)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I searched for the process that could be locking it using `ps aux | grep -i apt`
, but I don't know if i can stop any of these:

```
root      2459  0.0  0.0   4636   764 ?        Ss   13:22   0:00 /bin/sh/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
root      2470  0.0  0.0   4636  1644 ?        S    13:22   0:00 /bin/sh/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held update
suzana   11440  0.0  0.0  14444  1020 pts/0    S+   13:35   0:00 grep -i apt
```

Comment: 2 options to solve reboot or kill. in case of the last you have to run manually the command again

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` and `apt` are used by `apt.systemd.daily` service, you need to find and kill each process based on the output of `ps` command:

```
sudo kill -9 dpkg-process
sudo kill -9 apt-process
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```